# No join columns

Tags: playframework, persistence, ebean

I am new to Ebeans / Play 2.0.4, I am trying to model the following:

```
One question has many answers
```

So my classes look like this:

**Question model:**

```
package models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

@Entity
public class Question extends Model {
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
}
```

**Answer model:**

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

@Entity
public class Answer extends Model {
    @Id
    public Integer id;
}
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No join columns
```

What am I doing wrong? Further in the generated DDL I need "on update cascade" - is CascadeType.ALL the correct type for this? Thanks :-)

Comment: set the `answers` as `public`: `public List<Answer> answers;`

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but I am still getting the same error ):

Comment: Try by adding an Id to your question Entity.

Comment: Nota bene is that whole code of your models ? (if yes - it misses some parts) - edit your question and show as everything.

Comment: added the complete models code (just an id in the answer because even this minimalistic case is not working \:)

Answer (score 1):

Add the Id to the question entity:

```
@Entity
public class Question extends Model {
    @Id
    Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
}
```

Under the hood, Ebean to access the question properties generates a query like:

```
select * from question q join answer a where q.id = 123
```

in you entities q.id is missing